# Login to wordpress with filezilla client

Tags: login, ftp

I'm trying to login WordPress by using a Filezilla client, but I'm not sure if my log in details are correct because I'm using the login details that I use to login my website as admin, but maybe I need to put the login I use in the hosting service?

Comment: That is off-topic when you already know what to do!

Comment: as you can see in the answer provided, it's not exactly what I was doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use FTP login details( Filezilla is FTP client) to log in.Get the details from your hosting provider.

WordPress login details don't work.

Also hosting login details are different to FTP login details.